# What's the correct way to start a Ubuntu Upstart script from another Upstart script?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, upstart

I have three Ubuntu Upstart scripts:

- `browser` runs an instance of firefox as an unprivileged user
- `browsers` starts when `screen` is started and launches

  - `browser PORT=1`
  - `browser PORT=2`
  - `browser PORT=3`
- `screen` starts a Xvfb server

The chain is:

1. `screen` starts at runlevels 2, 3, 4, 5
2. `browsers` is configured to `start on started screen` and to `stop on stopping screen`
3. each instance `browser PORT=?` will `stop on stopping browsers` and will be started by `browsers`

## Issue

`screen` starts fine but doesn't start `browsers` (or it does and `browsers` fails to start `browser PORT=?`).

If I `sudo start browser PORT=1` everything works fine, whereas `sudo start browsers` doesn't even start itself.

## Code

```
#screen.conf
env DISPLAY=:99
env USER=worker

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script 
        su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/Xvfb ${DISPLAY}"
end script

#browsers.conf
start on started screen
stop on runlevel [!2345] or stopping screen

respawn

expect fork #the following "start browser ..." do fork

script
       start browser PORT=4242
       start browser PORT=4243
       start browser PORT=4244
       start browser PORT=4245
end script

#browser.conf
instance $PORT

stop on runlevel [!2345]
stop on stopping browsers or stopping screen

respawn

script 
        su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/firefox -no-remote -P ${PORT} --display ${DISPLAY}"
end script
```

**UPDATE (10/21/2010):** the (modified) code above now works. However, when I need to `stop browsers`, all the instances of `browser PORT=?` are correctly terminated, while ``browsers` gets stuck.

How do I solve this other issue?

Comment: It's important to know what version of upstart you use.

Comment: @JanC: 0.6.5-7 on Lucid Lynx Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucid comes with upstart v0.6.x, which means you can't have multiple "stop on" or "start on" lines.  You have to combine the conditions together with `and`, `or` & parentheses.

You can read the job description syntax in the init(5) manpage ([available online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/init.5.html) or run `man 5 init` in a terminal).

Comment: using the right syntax solved my problems, i.e., now they boot. Unfortunately, to make browsers booting I had to put "expect fork" (because "start browser PORT=4242" forks). This causes "sudo stop browsers" to stuck). Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe it forks too often so that upstart doesn't know the correct PID (that's a known problem with the current upstart, and which should be fixed in the next release of it)